# Keras Regression Not predicting below a certain value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying regression on a time series data, but am not getting acceptable predictions below a certain value. It's a time series trading data with the last 20% used for testing and predictions.

I am using the following parameters:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

def BuildModel():
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=13,activation='relu')) 
 model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu')) 
 model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu')) 
 model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu')) 
 model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
 model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=opt)   
 return model
```

After comparing the test and predicted labels, I am getting this:

[image]

Now, I don't know why the predictions are not working below a certain value.

I have tried the regression on both raw values, as well as scaled up values, through MinMaxScaler:

```
scaler01 = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X_scaled = scaler01.fit_transform(df_01)
```

I have tried on both raw, as well as scaled features (Y).

My guess is that either I am doing something wrong with the scaling, or since there are less features (OHLC) below that value, it's not predicting correctly.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the code of preparing the data? I suspect something wrong over there

Comment: So are you telling me your model predicts all these values *exactly* right except for that bottom part, without ever having seen this data and no other features? I don't believe that that is possible. Probably you are testing on the train set, it memorised all of it except for the test part you left out: the bottom 20%.

Comment: @jorijnsmit I am sure that's the testing dataset, and is not used in training. Just checked the whole code again.

Comment: @chhibbz, You can try shuffling the Data before `partitioning` it to `Train` and `Test`. If that doesn't work, please share the complete code so that we can have a look. Thanks!